# HtmlAgilityPack id selection

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am building a C# program, which goes on a website and takes a span#id.

Here is my code :

```
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(url);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(21000);
        string adress = doc.DocumentNode
              .SelectSingleNode("//td/span#myId")
              .Attributes["value"].Value;
```

And I always get this error "system.Xml.XPath.XpathException" :

[image: error system.Xml.XPath.XpathException]

Thanks

Comment: Your code is insufficient to understand your error and also, error information is not in English. Translate entire error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your HTML looks something like this:

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="testedAddress">Some text here</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Then the XPath you want is `//td/span[@id='testedAddress']`